# reference an assembly not in /bin or in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to load a managed DLL that's neither in my application's /bin directory nor in the GAC.  Is there a way add it to `system.web/compilation/assemblies` in web.config by path?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to copy it to bin directory?

Comment: If I have to, I'll make that work.  But I'd prefer not to have to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is, of course, to put the assembly in /bin like a normal person.  If for some reason you find yourself needing to reference assemblies from another path, there's [the `assemblyBinding` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can put in web.config to cause it to look elsewhere.